# SQL Report Builder 3 - regex to query only UK postal codes in a defined area

Tags: regex

REGEX novice needs help!

I have the following code but I need to tweak so it only validates **UK** post codes for BN, RH, SE, SM, TN, KT, PO, CR, W, WC, EC, SW, SE.

```
(GIR 0AA)|((([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY]))))[0-9][A-Z-[CIKMOV]]{2})
```

I have tried another similar code which did work with some intervention but I could not remove the cross-match variables in the INWARD AND OUTWARD part i.e. needing 'SE' and avoiding 'SO' etc.

Comment: Can you please mention some examples of UK postal codes?

Comment: the inward parts range from BN1 to WC1A and all the variables within the defined ALPHA part of the outward - being - BN, RH, SE, SM, TN, KT, PO, CR, W, WC, EC, SW & SE.